# Solve integral from Bishop via integration by parts

Tags: probability, integration

I am reading a Bishop's book and during derivation of equations, I got stuck on solving algebra via integration by parts (per partes).
For clarity

- $L$ (in decision theory and ML) is a function that evaluates an error
  of system
- $p$ is probability density function
- $\boldsymbol{x}$ is an input vector
- $t$ is an expected function output
- $y(\boldsymbol{x})$ is a value estimated by function for regression $y$

Assume we have a function called `loss function` $L$.
$$\mathbb{E}[L] =\int{\int{L(t,y(\boldsymbol{x}))p(\boldsymbol{x},t) d\boldsymbol{x}}dt}$$

A common choice of loss function is so called `squared loss function`
$$\mathbb{E}[L] =\int{\int{y(\boldsymbol{x}-t)^2p(\boldsymbol{x},t) d\boldsymbol{x}}dt}$$

The goal of curve-fitting in regression is to choose function $y(\boldsymbol{x})$ that minimizes $\mathbb{E}[L]$, we want to find minimum and solve it for $y(\boldsymbol{x})$

$$\frac{\delta\mathbb{E}[L]}{\delta y(\boldsymbol{x})} = 2\int y(\boldsymbol{x}-t)p(\boldsymbol{x},t)dt$$

Now I would like to express $y(\boldsymbol{x})$ so I used per partes (I know there is easier solution, when we just multiply it and play with integrals, but I am interested in why per partes does not work, or what I am doing wrong).
In per partes, $u$ and $v$ are functions dependent on $x$:
$$\int uv dx = x\int v dx - \int u'\Big(\int v dx\Big)dx$$

So when applied to previous equation and set equal to $0$
$$(y(\boldsymbol{x})-t) \int p(\boldsymbol{x},t) dt - \int (-1) \int p(\boldsymbol{x},t) dt dt = 0$$
Express $y(\boldsymbol{x})$
$$y(\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{-\int\int p(\boldsymbol{x},t)dtdt}{\int p(\boldsymbol{x},t)dt} + t$$
using `sum rule`
$$y(\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{-\int p(\boldsymbol{x})dt}{p(\boldsymbol{x})} + t = \frac{- t p(\boldsymbol{x})}{p(\boldsymbol{x})} + t = 0$$

**which is not the expected result.**
The result in book is actually
$$ \frac{\int t p(\boldsymbol{x}) dt}{p(\boldsymbol{x})} $$

See [Bishop](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf), page 46 for more detail (eq. 1.86 to 1.89)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the rule incorrectly stated for integration per parts. You should keep in mind that: 
$$d(uv) = udv + vdu \Rightarrow \int udv = uv - \int udv. $$
In your case I would recommend working with $u =p(x, t)$ y $dv = y(x)-t$. However, it does not make sense to make such integral because they are only asking by $ y (x) $. It is enough to do the following:

$$\int (y(x)-t)p(x, t)dt = 0 \Rightarrow \int y(x)p(x, t)dt - \int tp(x,t)dt = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow  \int y(x)p(x, t)dt = \int tp(x,t)dt \Rightarrow  y(x) \int p(x, t)dt = \int tp(x,t)dt$$

and as $\int p(x, t)dt = p(x)$ then you have: $y(x)p(x) = \int tp(x, t)dt$. Good luck!

Comment: The rule is correct, apart from that I derived it myself, the same can be found on Wikipedia or Mathisfun sources (https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/integration-by-parts.html). Also the solution you have just provided is correct and I found it myself. This is what I mean by `I know there is easier solution, when we just multiply it and play with integrals, but I am interested in why per partes does not work, or what I am doing wrong`

Comment: You're right. Your expression is equivalent to that given by Bishop. Notice that $$y(x) = \frac{-\int\int p(x, t)dt dt}{\int p(x, t) dt }+t = \frac{t\int p(x, t) dt-\int\int p(x, t)dt dt}{\int p(x, t) dt}$$. You can see that by integrating per parts we have: $$t\int p(x, t) dt-\int\int p(x, t)dt dt = \int tp(x, t) dt$$.

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution I was looking  for! Awesome!

Comment: But it is still unclear to me, why it is also equal to `0`. Or what have I done wrong, that `0` shows up.

Comment: You have to be clear that $\frac{\partial \mathbb{E}(L)}{\partial y(x)} = 0$ and not $y(x)$. You start with: $$\frac{\partial \mathbb{E}(L)}{\partial y(x)} = 2\int (y(x)-t)p(x, t)dt =0.$$ And you replace this equation by $$(y(x) -t)\int p(x, t)dt + \int \int p(x, t) dt dt = 0.$$ Note that you have never integrated the zero, have  only replaced the integral.

Comment: In fact I derived that $y(\boldsymbol{x}) = 0$, not that derivative is equal to 0.
$$y(\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{-\int\int p(\boldsymbol{x},t)dtdt}{\int p(\boldsymbol{x},t)dt} + t =  \frac{-\int p(\boldsymbol{x})dt}{p(\boldsymbol{x})} + t = \frac{- t p(\boldsymbol{x})}{p(\boldsymbol{x})} + t =-t+t= 0$$
but at the same time
$$y(\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{-\int\int p(\boldsymbol{x}, t)dt dt}{\int p(\boldsymbol{x}, t) dt }+t = \frac{t\int p(\boldsymbol{x}, t) dt-\int\int p(\boldsymbol{x}, t)dt dt}{\int p(\boldsymbol{x}, t) dt}=  \frac{\int tp(\boldsymbol{x}, t) dt}{\int p(\boldsymbol{x}, t) dt}$$